# how do i get email address from facebook using fos facebook bundle

Tags: symfony-2.3, fosfacebookbundle

I have successfully integrated my fos facebook bundle with my symfony2 application.But no email address in the resulting data.Is it possible to get email address of the logged in person using fos facebook bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Have you setted the permission?

```
 fos_facebook:
     alias:  facebook
     app_id: xxxxxxxxxxx
     secret: xxxxxxxxxxx
     cookie: true
     permissions: [email, user_hometown, user_location]
```

Comment: Yes.But it didn't returned email id.